# MS Access Report from MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm trying to get some information from a mysql database to a report in access. But I can't figure out how to get the information there since I'm using DAO connections in vba and cant use linked tables.

I've tried storing the information into a string from the form that I already have the information at through a DAO connection directly to mysql db with no luck.

```
Private Sub Command67_Click()
 DoCmd.Save
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        Me.Label39.Visible = True

        Dim strWhere As String

        strWhere = "[ID] = " & Me.[Id]

        DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , strWhere
End Sub
```

I use preview in that code to see some result but what I would like to do is print directly to the printer since this is a client turn receipt i need those to print fast.

Again I can't use linked tables.

Comment: Another thing is that in access forms I've been able to get all the information I need from the mysql database through DAO connections because I can set the form recordset but reports dont have the recordset property. I thought they did which would be so much better in this case but they dont have them.

Comment: Maybe write records to a local 'temp' table - table is permanent but records are temporary.

Comment: Do you have to use DAO? ADO might be a better functioning option for your circumstances.

Comment: @SamM Unforunally Reports can only use DAO (beside ADP's), you can't set their Recordset like in Forms.

Comment: How is the forms recordset created (show)? Unless you use a special ADO driver there should be an MySQL ODBC Driver installed. That can be used by DAO with a passthrough query:

Comment: Where did you copied your code? It doesn't make any sense and leads to strWhere = "ID = " as Me.ID is NULL for new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating on your former questions (some should be linked to that question), I see the problem. You don't link the MySQL-Tables what would make things easier for you.

But you can still use queries! Just put your connection string (maybe`Globales.ConnString`in former questions) in the queries`ODBC Connection String`in query design->properties. That makes the query a passthrough-query that is passed to MySQL-Server directly, not using MDAC.

Just set the reports`RecordSource`to the name of the query.

You can also build the query in VBA, but you can't use a temporary QueryDef("") as you can't set the Reports-Recordset, so use a non temp one.

Example (assumes there is a QueryDef named QueryForReport):

```vb
Sub EditQueryDefPassthrough()

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QueryForReport")
    .Connect = "ODBC;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};" _
        & "Server=YourServerName;" _
        & "Database=YourDatabaseName;" _
        & "User=YourMysqlUserName;" _
        & "Password=MysqlPwdForUser;" _
        & "Option=3;" ' adapt this to your MySQL ODBC Driver Version and server settings

    .SQL = "SELECT `Field` FROM `TABLE` LIMIT 1,1;" 'put SQL here (MySQL SQL Dialect, not MS-Access!). You can't use Access functions here (like Replace(), ...,  but those of MySQL like Concat().
End With

End Sub
```

The QueryDef needs to be set before the Report_Load Event, but in Report_Open should be sufficent (e.g. if you want to use OpenArgs for building the SQL-String)